# Tree from two-dimensional array PDO

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I cant figure it out.
I have mysql table:

```
id  |  name    |  sub

1   | FirstTab |  0
2   | SecondTab|  0
3   | ThirdTab |  0
4   | FourthTab|  1
5   | FifthTab |  1
6   | SixthTab |  2
```

And I want to see tree like this:

```
- FirstTab
-- FourthTab
-- FifthTab
- SecondTab
-- SixthTab
- ThirdTab
```

So I got

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ...');
$sth->execute();
$sth->fetchAll();
```

And how I can make tree from $sth? Foreach doesnt help :(

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with database structure, removing the tag

Comment: what is the amount of data? does it require a pagination?

Comment: No, it doesnt. Just like example

Comment: I cant do it with 1 query. I can imagine this only with ArrayIterator but I guess it isnt right way

Comment: yes, for such a structure you need recursion to build a tree. Get all your data into array and then run a recursive function on it

Comment: I cant imagine this. Please give some example

Comment: Oh. I believe this link can give you some hints http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+recursion+tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im learned more about PDO and solved my problem.